# I tried installing react-router-dom and bootstrap but this error keeps popping up

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1423:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELPHINE\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-14T19_29_19_306Z-debug.log

I already tried the below command lines on terminal but none seems to be working.
npm config rm proxy
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
npm config set strict-ssl false

Comment: Mostly, this error pop sup due to two reasons: Either your internet connection is not good or there's some problem with your npm cache (Clear you cache and try again `npm cache clean --force`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: okay i was able to rectify the issue, first i manually typed the the dependencies i wanted, 
npm config edit (deleted the proxy and registry)
npm install, it worked